# SwiftUI: How to propagate gestures to parent

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI view very similar to this pseudocode using [swift-ui-drawer](https://github.com/maustinstar/swiftui-drawer):

```swift
ZStack() {

  AnyView()

  Drawer() {
      Text("Click to Switch List Content")
        .onTapGesture {
          print("code that runs when this is tapped")
        }

        List {
          // ... renders a list
        }
  }

}
```

I've noticed that when I have `.onTapGesture { }` I can not drag on the area occupied by the `Text("Click to Switch List Content")` view, because I assume it's handling the gesture and not bubbling/propagating up the gesture to the parent component.

I'm wondering if there's a way to write this so when users tap on the `Text` view it will go to `onTapGesture` but if they tap-hold-and-drag it'll get handled correctly (i.e. the print statement won't run, it'll drag the Drawer).

I noticed other components like the the [Picker](https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-create-segmented-control-in-swiftui/#creation) don't have this issue, you can tap on them and it'll switch between selections, and if you tap-hold-and-drag it won't switch selections it will do what I want, which is dragging the drawer.

Comment: Have you tried using a binding var or maybe environment var (if you want to share the value across children)?

Comment: Have you tried adding `.onLongPressGesture{...}` see also `LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 0.2)`, 
at: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/longpressgesture   or `SimultaneousGesture`